# R How find gaps in data and classify if gaps are to large

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis

I have the following kind of data:

```
all_exercises <- c(1,2,9,4,5,7,6,8,3)

user_id <- c(14,14,14,14,14,16,16,16,16,16)
exercise_id <- c(1,2,9,4,5,1,2,4,5,6)
df <- data.frame(user_id,exercise_id)

df

       user_id exercise_id
1       14           1
2       14           2
3       14           9
4       14           4
5       14           5
6       16           1
7       16           2
8       16           4
9       16           5
10      16           6
```

Now I am interested in finding user which did not take 3 to all exercises in a row. The order of the exercises is somewhat different from 1:9 and if user have their gap inbetween he is also to be considered. In my example user 14 dropped out because he did not take exercises 7,6,8,3. User 16 is not dropped out because the gaps of the exercises are at max 2.

Comment: You are looking for `diff`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution

```
df.gaps <- df %>%
  mutate(exercise_id = factor(exercise_id, all_exercises)) %>%
  arrange(user_id, exercise_id) %>%
  mutate(exercise_id_num = as.numeric(exercise_id)) %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(gap = lead(exercise_id_num) - exercise_id_num - 1)
  mutate(gap = ifelse(is.na(gap), nlevels(all_exercises)-exercise_id_num, no=gap))


df.gaps
   user_id exercise_id exercise_id_num   gap
     <dbl>      <fctr>           <dbl> <dbl>
1       14           1               1     0
2       14           2               2     0
3       14           9               3     0
4       14           4               4     0
5       14           5               5     4
6       16           1               1     0
7       16           2               2     1
8       16           4               4     0
9       16           5               5     1
10      16           6               7     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `dplyr`, but this is likely a duplicate...

```
library(dplyr)

df.gaps <- df %>%
  arrange(user_id, exercise_id) %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(gap = exercise_id - lag(exercise_id, default = 0))

df.gaps %>%
  filter(gap > 3)
```

`df.gaps` orders the data by `user_id` and `exercise_id` (assumes exercises go in order). We then `group_by` the `user_id` in order to create a window function difference (see [this window functions vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html)) -- I also set a default value of zero to not result in `NA`.

Finally, you can filter this new `df.gaps` data.frame to get your result.

---

A base `R` solution might look something like this:

```
df <- df[order(df$user_id, df$exercise_id), ]
temp <- by(df$exercise_id, df$user_id, function(x) diff(x) > 3)
sapply(temp, any)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! since the exercises are not ordered numerically, I have to to a intermediate step and sort it by all_exercises. 


df.gaps <- df %>%
  mutate(exercise_id = factor(exercise_id, all_exercises)) %>%
  arrange(user_id, exercise_id) %>%
  mutate(exercise_id = as.integer(exercise_id)) %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(gap = exercise_id - lag(exercise_id, default = 0))

Comment: however, I dont get the gaps in the end. E.g. user 14 has not worked on the last 4 exercises but since there is no entry, there is nothing to lag() with

Comment: gap = lead(exercise_id) - exercise_id
is the solution here